# Table Does Not Exists Code 1

Tags: android, sqlite

I know this question gets asked a lot and I have looked through all the answers and cant seem to fix the error. I am just trying to do a simple select all from one of my tables but I am getting an error saying `no such table ingredient (code 1)`. I have used the same syntax in the create statement as two other tables that I know work so I dont know where I have gone wrong.

Any guidance will be greate

**Create Statement**

```
//Ingredient create statement
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_INGREDIENTS = "CREATE TABLE "
        + INGREDIENTS_TABLE + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT,"
        + KEY_RECIPE_CODE + " INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT, "
        + KEY_INGREDIENT_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + " FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_RECIPE_CODE+") REFERENCES " +RECIPE_TABLE+"("+KEY_CODE+"));";
```

**Ingredient Column Names**

```
//Ingredient column names
public static final String KEY_RECIPE_CODE ="reciep_code";
public static final String KEY_INGREDIENT_NAME ="ingredient_name";
public static final String KEY_MEASUREMENT = "measurement";
```

**Select all function**

```
public Cursor possibleRecipes()
{
    return db.query(INGREDIENTS_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENTS_NAME}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

**Calling the function from the class**

```
    Cursor cursor = adapter.possibleRecipes();
```

Comment: Nope no special characters, I have updated the question showing the column names I am using. I added the table from the creation of the database and have un installed the app and reinstalled it again to make sure the table does get created

Comment: I assume the table `INGREDIENTS_TABLE` has a value of `"ingredients"`. Or does it?

Comment: Sorry yes it does, `private static final String INGREDIENTS_TABLE = "ingredients";` is the string I am using

Comment: This seems like a typo, to me: `public static final String KEY_RECIPE_CODE ="reciep_code";` I mean `reciep` should be `recipe`

Comment: Very well spotted, that fixed it thank you so much! I had been staring at it for too long and thought the spelling was right!